# Solvability of a randomly put together Rubiks’s cube

Tags: probability, group-theory, rubiks-cube

After taking my Rubik’s cube apart, (leaving me with 12 edge pieces, 8 corner pieces and the center piece) and putting it back together randomly, I noticed that the cube is only solvable sometimes, while other times it cannot be solved by the legal rotations.

Now my question is: What is the probability that a Rubik’s cube that is randomly put together like that is solvable?
From trying it out a few times I suspect that the probability is probably lower than $0.5$, maybe something like $[0.2 - 0.3]$, but that’s only a very rough estimate.

I don’t really know how to start on this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe somewhere, but anyway you have overestimated as the answer is I believe 1/12 due to cube invariants. http://blog.kleinproject.org/?p=2130

Comment: There is a 1/12 probability that a cube randomly put together is solvable. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256343/rubiks-cube-combination/277099 for some explanations.